# Sharepoint: WSS Index returning warnings, how to read?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

Last week I was unable to perform any searches using my WSS index based search web part, looking into the WSS search database I saw that I started getting hundreds of WarningCounts per crawl in the MSSCrawlHistory table.  After performing 'stsadm -o spsearch -action fullcrawlstart' to perform a full crawl the warnings went away for about a day.  I was getting less than 10 warnings per incremental crawl until the next day when I was back to getting hundreds.

Is it possible to see these warnings?  I have tried setting up logging through central admin, adding anything that looked search related, and I didn't get much of anything that looked relevant to the warnings I was looking for (I was hoping to see 900 or so of the same warning to make things easy, no luck).

The index in question is the WSS index, not a MOSS Shared Service index.  The corresponding db for this index is at WSS_Search_SERVERNAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that both occurrences of this have happened at the same time that I retracted my solutions.  Around the time of the retract, I would start getting those warnings.  So going on that hunch, I retracted, performed a full crawl, and sure enough I got a bunch of warnings.  I was able to do this with one of my MOSS SSPs also (performed full crawl within the SSP while retracted), and the warnings were all 'deleted by the gatherer' which is something I've seen come up a lot in google.

After deploying my solutions again I was able to index without strange warnings (although I needed to crawl a couple of times and perform an iisreset before reducing the warning count back to normal level).